# WImax Module of NS2 - PT_DCCP_REQ error during installation

Tags: ns2

WImax Module of NS2 giving me this error during installation can anyone help me?

> dccp/dccp.cc:649:19: error: ‘PT_DCCP_REQ’ was not declared in this
>   scope dccp/dccp.cc:657:19: error: ‘PT_DCCP_RESP’ was not declared in
>   this scope dccp/dccp.cc:665:20: error: ‘PT_DCCP_ACK’ was not declared
>   in this scope dccp/dccp.cc:674:20: error:
>   ‘PT_DCCP_DATA’ was not declared in this scope
>   dccp/dccp.cc:683:20: error: ‘PT_DCCP_DATAACK’ was not declared in this
>   scope dccp/dccp.cc:686:20: error: ‘PT_DCCP_ACK’ was
>   not declared in this scope dccp/dccp.cc:696:21:
>   error: ‘PT_DCCP_ACK’ was not declared in this scope
>   dccp/dccp.cc:726:19: error: ‘PT_DCCP_CLOSEREQ’ was not declared in
>   this scope dccp/dccp.cc:731:19: error:
>   ‘PT_DCCP_CLOSE’ was not declared in this scope
>   dccp/dccp.cc:765:7: error: ‘PT_DCCP_DATA’ was not declared in this
>   scope dccp/dccp.cc:768:7: error: ‘PT_DCCP_ACK’ was
>   not declared in this scope dccp/dccp.cc:771:7: error:
>   ‘PT_DCCP_DATAACK’ was not declared in this scope

Answer (score 0):

---

ns-2.35 + wimax, please see post #6 here ...

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/install-wimax-in-ns2-35-a-4175523810/#6

---

And ns-2.34 + wimax, another post #6 / another thread :

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/erreur-when-install-ns2-34-a-4175524406/#6

---

Kind Regards , knudfl.

---

[ns2](/questions/tagged/ns2)